# How we can avoid many release?

Tags: java, resources

I don't know If I'm breaking the policy of stack-overflow by asking this type of question or no?

In our JEE application, we have some mathematics formulas (for some useful calculation) hardcoded, the issue is that if we want to add new formulas that require new release and we want to avoid this by copied this formula in SQL table then we will use in our APP for the calculation.

Could you tell me is this good idea?

Comment: Hardcoding things is usually a bad idea. Especially so when you know the thing you're hardcoding will change.

Comment: yes Mr. @Kayaman, really I'm doing investigationin this issue about couples of days but I failed

Comment: What about some configuration file that may be extended and deployed manually or at least with a separate tool? But it totally depends on the architecture of your program…

Comment: No need to call me Mr. Kayaman, that's my father's name. It's a simple decision between hardcoding and not hardcoding the formulas. If you don't want to make a new release for modifying the forrmulas, then you can't hardcode them. Where and how you store them is up to you.

Comment: This question is highly subjective, so it's not a good fit for Stackoverflow.  There are many questions that cannot be easily answered. How costly is a new release? How easy it is to represent mathematical formulas in the database, then translate them into a format that can be used from Java....? Isn't there a risk to fall into an Inner Platform Effect? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect)

Comment: @deHaar I will explain more what is our challenge, the formulas depend on (Eg. f1 = a+b+c)
a, b, and c can be in data base or input text in UI.
the user can add other furmulas f2 = a*b-c+d without hardcoded

Comment: Basically, you need to define a user configuration file (e.g. xml) which may be edited and read at runtime. Protect your formulae from getting deleted by a user (users should only delete their own formulae) and you're good. How you implement the access to that file depends on the architecture as I stated above. Write some class(es) that enable the user to access a configuration.

Comment: @deHaar If you're modifying data, it belongs in a database. No use in hacking around with some custom XML approach.

Comment: @Kayaman Probably the best way to go, yes. The idea came to my mind because there is no code and no uml in the question, so I thought about an alternative way without making use of SQL (altering db structure will require a release).

Answer (score -1):

Having the formula stored in database will imply that you will load and execute it dynamically, which will have a performance impact.

You may store it as a script (even in the database if you want to) and compile it once at runtime (see javax.script package and [Compilable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/Compilable.html) implementations)

You may also dynamically classLoad implementation of a pre-defined interface of your choice (typical example of a strategy design pattern) and will so have to release only new algorithms).

For a more mature approach you can have a look to [OSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) framework (which allow to dynamically load components) but it's a bit out of fashion or [java 9 new modularity approach](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) (which I don't know)

Comment: An overly complicated suggestion starting with an imaginary performance impact scare that doesn't answer the question (also, the question isn't suitable for SO).

Comment: Well I work on a system which used to load scripts from database (since replaced by spring bean names and a strategy pattern) and still load groovy scripts from disk. Dynamically evaluating code has a performance impact

Comment: Sure, but I doubt he's working on the same system as you are, he's talking about formulas and not code, and this isn't related to performance in any way. Your suggestions are plain overengineering for what's involved.

Comment: I'd be happy to understand how formulas are different from code

Comment: I'm a bit worried that someone with a title of Senior Developer thinks that code and formulas are the same thing (barring in `FORTRAN` of course!).